# Dynamically update Dynamic UI for R Shiny

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, dynamic

This is code from Chapter 10 of Mastering Shiny.  Does anyone know how to make the UI filter (output$filter) update as selections are made?  Presently only the output$data table output changes.  I'd like to see the sliders and select inputs on the UI change as a selection is made on any of the sliders/selects.  Right now the filter UI ranges and selections don't change because they only depend on the reactives vars and data.

```
library(shiny, purrr)

dfs <- purrr::keep(ls("package:datasets"), ~ is.data.frame(get(.x, "package:datasets")))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dataset", label = "Dataset", choices = dfs),
      uiOutput("filter")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("data")
    )
  )
)

make_ui <- function(x, var) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    rng <- range(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    sliderInput(var, var, min = rng[1], max = rng[2], value = rng)
  } else if (is.factor(x)) {
    levs <- levels(x)
    selectInput(var, var, choices = levs, selected = levs, multiple = TRUE)
  } else {
    # Not supported
    NULL
  }
}

filter_var <- function(x, val) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    !is.na(x) & x >= val[1] & x <= val[2]
  } else if (is.factor(x)) {
    x %in% val
  } else {
    # No control, so don't filter
    TRUE
  }
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    get(input$dataset, "package:datasets")
  })
  vars <- reactive(names(data()))
  
  output$filter <- renderUI(
    purrr::map(vars(), ~ make_ui(data()[[.x]], .x))
  )
  
  selected <- reactive({
    each_var <- purrr::map(vars(), ~ filter_var(data()[[.x]], input[[.x]]))
    purrr::reduce(each_var, `&`)
  })
  
  output$data <- renderTable(head(data()[selected(), ], 12))
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So far I've tried using lapply after the renderUI and wrapping the output$filter section with observeEvent(output$data...) or bindEvent, and these have not worked for me.